# Jacoco: jacocoTestResport working ok but jacocoTestCoverageVerification always shows 0 coverage

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jacoco

I wanted to make some simple Unit Tests plus its coverage report: Actually everything works ok but the code coverage tasks always responds that there is 0% coverage

Actually I'm using Gradle 5.6; Jacoco 0.8.4

I tried verifying if the test coverage isn't reading the .exec file, but it does.
I excluded all the beans because they uses lombok notations, to avoid synthetic code and coverage problems (anyway the problem persists)

```
/*Especificación de cobertura de código para test unitarios
-Qué clases incluir y excluir en la cobertura
-De las clases incluidas
    --Mínimo de % de cobertura ok

Además agregamos rutina de jacocoTestReport en tarea de tests
*/

jacocoTestReport {

    getClassDirectories().setFrom(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                    exclude: ['example/config/*',
                    'example/dto/*',
                    'example/model/configuration/*'])
        })


    getSourceDirectories().setFrom(sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs)

    getExecutionData().setFrom(
        fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/jacoco", include:["**/*.exec"]))

    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
    }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {

    getClassDirectories().setFrom(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                    exclude: ['example/config/*',
                    'example/dto/*',
                    'example/model/configuration/*'])
        })


    getSourceDirectories().setFrom(sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs)

    getExecutionData().setFrom(
        fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/jacoco", include:["**/*.exec"]))

    violationRules {

        rule {
            enabled = true
            limit {
                counter = 'INSTRUCTION'
                value = 'COVEREDRATIO'
                //minimum = 0.05
                /*Los test actuales cubren el 6% del código
                Este requisito debería fallar*/
                minimum = 0.1
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Actually i want to reproduce the behavior to fail the coverage test because JacocoTestReport in the htmlReport shows that the total of Instructions coverage is 6%, but the console's message always shows that the value is zero

"[ant:jacocoReport] Rule violated for bundle example-ms: instructions covered ratio is 0.0, but expected minimum is 0.1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':jacocoTestCoverageVerification'.

  > Rule violated for bundle example-ms: instructions covered ratio is 0.0, but expected minimum is 0.1"

I'm adding JacocoTestReport in the test task (using finalize)...it works ok
After that if i execute the gradle jacocoTestCoverageVerification it always shows the mesagge described above